# Allow comment homepage URLs without http://

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I want Drupal comments to work like every other blog's comments. Who are writing their homepage URL can write "www.example.com," or "http://www.example.com," and they both work. Right now, Drupal throws an error if the URL doesn't contain "http://."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override the `comment_validate` hook in `/modules/comment/comment.module` and modify the validation code to insert the `http://` bit into the URL if it's not already there. The changed code would look something like:

```
if ($edit['homepage']) {
    if (!strpos($edit['homepage'], "http://")) {
        $edit['homepage'] = "http://" . $edit['homepage'];
    }
    if (!valid_url($edit['homepage'], TRUE)) {
        form_set_error('homepage', t('The URL of your homepage is not valid. Remember that it must be fully qualified, i.e. of the form <code>http://example.com/directory</code>.'));
    }
}
```

You would also need to override the `comment_form_validate` hook:

```
function comment_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid === 0) {
    foreach (array('name', 'homepage', 'mail') as $field) {
      // Set cookie for 365 days.
      if (isset($form_state['values'][$field])) {
        setcookie('comment_info_'. $field, $form_state['values'][$field], time() + 31536000, '/');
      }
    }
  }
  $form_state['values'] = comment_validate($form_state['values']);
}
```

Comment: this can work. but when i click the vistor's homepage. it can't work. the url is: http://example.com/test.com

Comment: I've modified the answer to add a hook on comment_form_validate that should fix the problem...

Comment: it's ok. many thanks. but i don't know why it can work. you just assign the comment_validate($form_state['values']); to the $form_state['values'].expect you can explain it

Comment: The `comment_validate` function returns the change to `$edit['homepage']` but it's not assigned to anything in `comment_form_validate` so the change is dropped when the function returns. `$edit['homepage']` comes from `$form_state['values']` and `$form_state` is passed into `comment_form_validate` by reference so the modification stays after the function finishes.

Comment: i am sorry. there is a new question comeing. when i input the (http://   www.example.com), it can't submit the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The strpos line should be

```
strpos($edit['homepage'], "http://") === FALSE
```

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/allow-comment-homepage-urls-without-http